# $L^\infty$ norm bounded by $L^2$ norm of certain derivatives

Tags: analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

In Michael Taylor's PDE - Nonlinear equations, there are two estimates (3.28) & (3.29), that he says can be easily seen. I have tried Fourier transform and fundamental theorem in calculus to express the $L^{\infty}$ norm, but I still cannot efficiently relate it to the $L^2$ norm in the inequalities. I will appreciate if anyone can offer a proof of them. The inequalities are listed below.

$\Vert{u}\Vert^2_{L^\infty}\le C\Vert D^{m+1}u\Vert^2_{L^2} + C\Vert D^{m-1}u\Vert^2_{L^2}$ , for $u\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2m})$,

and

$\Vert{u}\Vert^2_{L^\infty}\le C\Vert D^{m+1}u\Vert^2_{L^2} + C\Vert D^{m}u\Vert^2_{L^2}$ , for $u\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2m+1})$,

within which $\Vert D^ku\Vert_{L^p} = \sum_{|\alpha|=k}\Vert D^{\alpha}u\Vert_{L^p}$

My trying using Fourier transform:

\begin{align}
u(x) &= C\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2m}}\ e^{ix\xi}\ \hat{u}(\xi)d\xi \\
     &= C\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2m}}\ e^{ix\xi}\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{(m+1)/2}}(1+|\xi|^2)^{(m+1)/2}\ \hat{u}(\xi)d\xi \\
   \implies |u(x)| &\le C\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2m}}\ |\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{(m+1)/2}}|\cdot|(1+|\xi|^2)^{(m+1)/2}\ \hat{u}(\xi)|d\xi\\
     &\le C\ [\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2m}}\ \frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{m+1}}d\xi]^{1/2}\cdot [\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2m}}\ (1+|\xi|^2)^{m+1}\ |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2d\xi]^{1/2} \\
     &= C\ [\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2m}}\ (1+|\xi|^2)^{m+1}\ |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2d\xi]^{1/2}.
\end{align}
I do know that there is an estimate of this form
$$c_{1,k}(1+|\xi|^2)^k\le\sum_{|\alpha|\le k}\xi^{2\alpha}\le c_{2,k}(1+|\xi|^2)^k$$
which I think I can use to have the following estimate
\begin{align}
|u(x)| &\le C\ [\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2m}}\ (1+|\xi|^2)^{m+1}\ |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2d\xi]^{1/2} \\
       &\le C\ [\sum_{|\alpha|\le m+1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2m}}\ \xi^{2\alpha}\ |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2d\xi]^{1/2}
\end{align}
That's where I was stuck. If I am summing over $|\alpha|\le m+1$, then it will lead me to the $H^{m+1}$ norm, but not just $\Vert D^{m+1}u\Vert_{L^2}$. I think the tricky point is that I cannot avoid the constant "1" or any positive constant $\epsilon$, or else the integral $[\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2m}}\ \frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{m+1}}\ d\xi]^{1/2}$ won't be finite.

My trying of fundamental theorem of calculus seems not to be applicable.

Comment: Can you kindly write down your attempt  and where you are stuck ?

Comment: At a high level: Try the following: Take the integral of derivatives corresponding to $L_2$ norm and lower bound the integral using integral corresponding to fundamental theorem of calculus and lower bound it by the value of the function.

Comment: @Balajisb Thanks for your comment. I'll put my trying process in the question part. Btw, could you explain more of your method. I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: I am attempting to prove  for $\alpha(1,1....,1)$:  $\int |D^{\alpha} f(x)| dx \geq \int_{B = [0,x_1],...,} |D^{\alpha} f(x)| dx \geq \int_B D^{\alpha} f(x) dx \geq constant \times (f(y)-f(a))$.\ where last inequality is by fundamental theorem of calculus and assumed uniform continuity of $f$ as constant must be independent of $y$. Need to prove $ \sum_{\alpha} \int |D^{\alpha} f(x)|^2 dx \geq constant \times \sum_{\alpha} \int |D^{\alpha} f(x)| dx$. Not sure if the last inequality is even true for smooth functions.

Comment: Try to see if you can fill in the gaps or u can directly prove skipping some of the inequalities i mentioned.

Comment: Try using convexity of $x^2$ and prove by jensen inequality, $\int |D^{\alpha} f|^2 dx \geq \int_B |D^{\alpha} f|^2 dx \geq constant \times 1/ |B| \times |\int_B |D^{\alpha} f| dx|^2$.

Comment: What you did is to follow the proof of the usual Sobolev’s embedding theorem. But in fact you can refine it slightly (a trick I learnt recently) as follows: split up $\int=\int_{|\xi|\leq 1}+\int_{|\xi|\geq 1}$. In the first region, multiply and divide by $|\xi|^{m-\epsilon}$ (I think $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ will reduce things nicely to integers, but just keep the $\epsilon$ around for now and check things at the end), and in the second region, use $|\xi|^{m+\epsilon}$. Then, use Cauchy-Schwarz as usual. The point is to utilize estimates suited to the origin and infinity separately.

Comment: The point is that now that you only used the weights $|\xi|^{m\pm\epsilon}$, this corresponds exactly to $m\pm\epsilon$ derivatives. So, if you choose $\epsilon$ correctly (I think $\frac{1}{2}$), then this means you only pick up the $m-1$ and $m+1$ order derivatives. You’re on the right track noticing that the role of the $1$ in $(1+|\xi|^2)$ is to ensure integrability, but that is way too crude of an estimate. The general “idea” is to use separate (but stronger) estimates in separate regions if necessary. This gives an overall improvement.

Comment: @peek-a-boo  Great! I just tried your method and I think it leads to the desired result. "The general “idea” is to use separate (but stronger) estimates in separate regions if necessary." is a very good saying. Thank you for the sharing which is highly appreciated!